# ZF2 Collection Validation

Tags: php, zend-framework2, formcollection

Is it possible to attach error messages to the Fieldset itself and not a child element in ZF2?  I have a form with two Fieldsets and I need ensure the elements that are filled in Fieldset1 are also filled in Fieldset2. (There are optional elements inside each fieldset, but if `Fieldset1->element1` is filled in, `Fieldset2->element1` needs to be filled in).

I have the validation working properly, but I receive an empty array when I call `$form->getMessages()`.

The messages aren't being set inside `Zend\Form\Fieldset::setMessages`
because its attempting to find an element by the error message key. (In my example below `'invalidDate'`).

I am attempting to add an error message to the Fieldset itself, because the error is not limited to one particular field, but the collection as a whole.

```
//Regular Error 
{
    start: {
        year: [
            regexInvalid: "SomeMessage"
        ]
    },
    end: {
        year: [
            regexInvalid: "SomeMessage"
        ]
    }
}

//Fieldset level Error 
{
    start: {
        invalidDate: [
            noMatch: "Filled in values of 'start' and 'end' must match"
        ]
    },
    end: {
        invalidDate: [
            noMatch: "Filled in values of 'start' and 'end' must match"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Update**

This is the validation for the `start` fieldset.  The validation works, I can compare the `start` and `end` fieldsets with the context param.  `start` and `end` contain elements such as year, month, week, day, etc.

```
return array(
    "name" => "start",
    "required" => true,
    "validators" => array(
        array(
            "name" => "Application\Validator\Start"
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve such fieldsets by making nested input filters (an input filter config for each fieldset. I showed one validator for year in the config to show you how this can work:

```
array(
    'start' => array(
        'day' => array(
            'name' => 'end',
            'required' => false
        ),
        'week' => array(
            'name' => 'end',
            'required' => false
        ),
        'month' => array(
            'name' => 'end',
            'required' => false
        ),
        'year' => array(
            'name' => 'end',
            'required' => false
        ),
        // type key necessary for nested input filter
        'type' => 'Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter'
    ),
    'end' => array(
        'day' => array(
            'name' => 'end',
            'required' => false
        ),
        'week' => array(
            'name' => 'end',
            'required' => false
        ),
        'month' => array(
            'name' => 'end',
            'required' => false
        ),
        'year' => array(
            'name' => 'end',
            'required' => false,
            'filters' => array(),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'Callback',
                    'options' => array(
                        'messages' => array(
                            Callback::INVALID_VALUE => "Filled in values of start year and end year must match",
                        ),
                        'callback' => function($value, $context = array()) {
                            // value of end
                            $endYear = $value;
                            // value of start year
                            $startYear = $context['start']['year'];
                            // validate
                            return $endYear >= $startYear;
                        }
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        // type key necessary for nested input filter
        'type' => 'Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter'
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Start and End are Fieldsets, not elements.  I have the validation done, but the messages aren't being returned when calling getMessages() because Start and End aren't actual elements.

Comment: great, have been searching for this solution for a while, is this actually documented somewhere?